# Why is it a bad idea to use React Directly in HTML (not in a react enviroment)?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react. W3schools says (in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_getstarted.asp)):

> The quickest way start learning React is to write React directly in your HTML files.
>
> This way of using React can be OK for testing purposes, but for production you will need to set up a React environment.

So my question is : Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid runtime react code compilation into Javascript which may consume lot of memory.

Your Browser do not understand React but JavaScript and when you are providing the `babel` to transpile your code, its not efficient and memory performant. So to make your app performant its advisable to create a bundle first and then deploy it to your webapp.

For learning purposes you can try developing an app by passing babel/react links and after sometimes you will surely feel that your browser starts hanging etc.

Comment: "Your Browser do not understand React", do you mean browser dont understand babel? because i thought React is a library like Jquery, and when we import it's js script, browser will recognize it. (i'm just asking, sorry if i'm wrong.)

Comment: @yayapro your JSX that browser do not understand

Comment: so if i don't use jsx, it's ok to use React directly in html?

Comment: yes, till the time its not started giving you pain to maintain your code :)

Comment: i already noticed the debugging and maintain problem :p thanks for answer <3